# how to create an API for registering tenants in django-tenant?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-tenants with a decoupled front end. Everything works for per-tenant apps, but I struggle to figure out to make an api for registering of tenants (and anything else from django-tenants). Obviously I'm lost about serializers,too.

For per-tenant user registration, I extend BaseUserManager from django.contrib.auth.base_user. This UserManager handles creating users. So, I would expect that django-tenant would have something like TenantManager, but django-tenant docs don't have documentation on that and I can't find it in code.

What django-tenants does have is custom user commands like create_tenant and create_tenant_superuser, which could be useful since in django you can access any management command like this:

> from django.core.management import call_command
>
> call_command('my_command', 'foo', bar='baz')

But django-tenants does not have the docs on that either. It seems to me that they're defined [here](https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants/blob/master/django_tenants/management/commands/create_tenant.py)  but the code is too complex for me, i don't know how to extent it in my app.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I also want to create tenants via an api.